# jenkins pipeline script ssh is rejecting private key

Tags: jenkins

I'm having a weird issue here with jenkins, here is a very basic pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
    
        agent any
        
       
        stages {
            stage('Tester') {
                steps {
                    script {
                      
                        sshagent(credentials: ['my-credentials-id']) {
                            
                            // Use ssh-keyscan to fetch the remote server's host key
                            def remoteHostKey = sh(script: "ssh-keyscan remote.server.com", returnStdout: true).trim()
        
                            // Append the host key to the known_hosts file
                            sh "echo '${remoteHostKey}' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts"
                    
                            sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@remote.server.com 'echo \"HELLO\"'"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

1. I have added the private key from the remote server for "user" to jenkins under credentials
2. I have tested the private key on my local machine like this: ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user user@remote.server.com and it works fine

So i'm assuming this is something to do with jenkins, the result in jenkins log:

> 13:07:36  + ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@remote.server.com
> echo "HELLO" 13:07:36  Permission denied, please try again. 13:07:36
> Permission denied, please try again. 13:07:36  Permission denied
> (publickey,password).